# Execute a file in VBScript with cscript.exe and not wscript.exe

Tags: vbscript

I know how to execute a exe with wscript.exe, something like this:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "c:\myprogram.exe"
```

But I'm forced to run my vbscript with cscript.exe, and can't use the WScript object. Are there any way to execute an exe when loaded with cscript.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both wscript.exe and cscript.exe provide the WScript object; so "Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject(...)" is okay for .vbs files started with "w|cscript.exe whatever.vbs". VBScript - the language - provides its own CreateObject() function, so you can use plain "Set WshShell = CreateObject(...)" in all scripts (.hta, html too). The WScript COM object is another object. You can use it 'everywhere' (if we disregard security settings). In short: your code will work (or fail) with both hosts.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the code to:
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
And then it worked, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.run("cscript d:\Test2.vbs")
```

Comment: While this may solve OP's issue, please provide explanation on the code