# Edit Registry using vbscript in a .hta file

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm looking to edit a reg key using a .hta file but have run into a couple of issues. I've been using VBScript because I'm most familiar with that, but the problem comes from not being able to use WScript.CreateObject in the .hta file. I'd been using this is other .wsf files:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\MyProgram\MyKey", "Value", "REG_SZ"
```

Has anyone tackled this problem before, or might know an alternative way of interacting with the registry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'plain' CreateObject() function ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) in VBScript, so use this in an .HTA where the WScript object (provided by c|wscript.exe) isn't available.

see also: [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6874014/603855), [even better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8915571/603855) answer to similar problem

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard!

I had tried that and couldn't get it to work but now I'm thinking it's more likely to be Windows 7 permission settings preventing the change, thus it wasn't passing my tests. Thats a whole other issue though hehe.

Comment: `WScript.CreateObject` (+ `WScript.ConnectObject`) are still useful 
(only in WSH environment though) then hook up [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974564.aspx)